# ImageSource Class on MSDN Mistake?

Tags: wpf, metadata, msdn, imagesource, bitmapsource

I am unclear of what this means from the definition on ImageSource class on MSDN:

> Represents a object type that has a width, height, and ImageMetadata such as a BitmapSource and a DrawingImage.

This is an abstract class, DrawingImage and BitmapSource both derive from ImageSource, they are not part of the metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a matter of associativity:

> Represents a object type --- that has a width, height, and ImageMetadata --- such as a BitmapSource and a DrawingImage

i.e. the `such as` does not belong to the `ImageMetadata`.